# How to enable Azure Mobile Service Remote Debugging

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, azure-mobile-services

how can i enable the remote debugging for a mobile service?

my setup: i create a new mobile service from VS 2015 CTP 6 (Azure SDK v2.5 Preview VS 2015) and publish it. Then i enable remote debugging on the azure portal for VS 2015.

After rightclick "Attach Debugger" in the server explorer this "enter your credentials" dialog appears. I enter den credentials from the publishProfile (MSDeploy: url\userName + userPWD) but it will not work :(

did i forget any settings? maybe the firewall? wrong domain for crednetials?

Thanks for any Help!

[image]